# Loading the same file in memory for each mapper hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I came across an algorithm where, the same file is loaded into the main memory for each mapper.

I assume that, we must use distributed cache to get the file, and read the file and load it into memory, for each mapper. When I implemented this, I found that the map was taking a long time to complete. I am assuming, it is because, the file is read every time from the local disc for each mapper value.

Am I correct in implementing it?

Is there any other suggestions?

Pls help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read from local disk in the Mapper setup() method.  Use an instance variable to hold on to the reference.

Comment: I ve made the implementation using job conf, the old api, is there the way to do that in old api?

Comment: Look at the configure() method.

Comment: So, if I read the file in the configure method out side of map method, then I will not have to read it again and again. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.  That's what the configure() method is for(). And if you have something that needs doing after all the map() calls, you'd put that logic in the close() method.  Note that the configure() and close() methods are called once for each input slice.  If 10 mappers run 3 times each (30 slices with many records each) to process all of your input, the configure() and close() will be called 30 times each.

Comment: Thank You So much! So, I will be reading the file 30 times for processing the entire input. Am I correct?

Comment: In my made-up example, yes, 30 times.